# Python equivalent to select.list in R

Tags: python, r

I am working in Python, and I have data I need to clean.  In R,

```
crazy.seq<-c(rep("a",6),"Hey",rep("b",8),"Good Looking ;)",rep("c",3))
happy.seq<-select.list(crazy.seq,multiple=T)
print(happy.seq)
```

To describe the behavior for those unfamiliar with R:
`crazy.seq` is a data structure with 19 values in it. `select.list` opens a user interface that allows the user to interactively select the index(ices) that should be placed in `happy.seq`.  After executing and receiving user input, `happy.seq` will have whichever elements from `crazy.seq` the user selected.

Is there a python equivalent?

Comment: Could you explain what is your input, and what is the output you're looking for?

Comment: @edouardtheron He did, but it's in R.

Comment: I kind of get the input indeed (even not knowing R) but I can't figure out what is the expected output...

Comment: @edouardtheron It basically gives a gui output that you use a mouse to select variables from the vector.

Comment: @edouardtheron "a"               "a"               "a"               "a"              
 "a"               "a"               "Hey"             "b"              
 "b"               "b"               "b"               "b"              
 "b"               "b"               "b"               "Good Looking ;)"

Comment: No, there is no built in Python equivalent. Maybe there is a third party module that implements this but Ive never heard of one. Python is a general purpose programming language, not a dedicated statistical programming environment. Don't expect functions that open up a GUI interface to exist in the language itself.

Comment: From [docs](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/utils/versions/3.4.3/topics/select.list), looks like it opens a Tcl/Tk list box widget. Consider building a Python `tkinter` listbox for list of values for user selection.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga it's not necessarily a GUI interface. If no graphics device is available it just sends it to the console, gets input from the keyboard, and indexes the object according to the index values the user entered. Since the OP didn't open a graphics device, I presumed that was the desired behavior.

Comment: @DanHall, it is close to the desired behavior, but when you see the values i want to pick out, the GUI is desired since i want to select multiple variables. menu(), the console equivalent to select.list() only allows a single selection.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by console equivalent. `select.list()` runs in interactive sessions (only). Did you want the behavior of `tk_select.list()`?

Comment: @Danhall, yes. That is essentially what i am looking for in python,  I've noticed i can import tk into python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not a python standard library implementation of this. You could write one though:

```
crazy = [1, 'a', 'a', 'b']
# Ask the user for some index values
happy = [crazy[int(i)] for i in input("Enter index values separated by a space: ").split()]
```

For example, if the user inputs `0 3`, the state of the variables is:

```
crazy
# [1, 'a', 'a', 'b']
happy
# [1, 'b']
```

Comment: can you call something like 1:4?

Comment: @MadmanLee you'd have to plan for that and code it to accept and evaluate that input. But as I recall, you'd end up with a security vulnerability. It's been a little while since I was coding in python daily.